# Lightbox error when transferring codes to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, typeerror

I am implementing a JQuery Lightbox on a website I'm working on. The same set of codes work very well in localhost, but when I transfer the codes to my server, I get this error concerning the lightbox. `Uncaught TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'extend'` . I have no idea what error this signifies.

Also I only have jQuery lib on the page.

here is the page I'm working on [mypage](http://tapmichiana.org/immigration-reform.php)

Please help me.

**Update**

I added `<script>jQuery.noConflict();});</script>` within `<head></head>` of html..in between jquery lib and lightbox script link. But still not working.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see that error.. and the lightbox works fine for me.. How/When are you seeing that error in console?

Comment: @wirey the error shows here and i dont know why

Comment: Open up your developer tools (f12) - go to the networking tab..  hit refresh..  see if any of your js files are failing to load

Comment: @wirey js files loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working well, you may try to reupload lightbox.css to fix alignment issue.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times that error happens when a dependent script is missing. It can also happen if you are using multiple libraries besides jQuery.

Comment: I'm only using jQuery libs.

Comment: All js files are loading successfully